# Integer Type conversion in yaml

Tags: types, yaml, istio, spinnaker

The below is my `istio yaml` for traffic shifting. I am getting the below error if I pass parameter in spinnaker. I am sending only integer values like 10, 20 etc.

"json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type int32"

Can I change the string to integer in yaml ?

```
- apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
  kind: VirtualService
  metadata:
    name: webvs
    namespace: default
  spec:
    gateways:
      - xyz.default.svc.cluster.local
      - mesh
    hosts:
      - web.xyz.com
    http:
      - route:
          - destination:
              host: web.default.svc.cluster.local
              port:
                number: 8080
              subset: v1
            weight: '${ parameters.Prodweightb }'
          - destination:
              host: web.default.svc.cluster.local
              port:
                number: 8080
              subset: v2
            weight: '${ parameters.Blineweightb }'
          - destination:
              host: web.default.svc.cluster.local
              port:
                number: 8080
              subset: v3
            weight: '${ parameters.Canaryweightb }'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your yaml is that there are single quotes around the int parameter value. Try to remove them, for example:

```
weight: ${ parameters.Canaryweightb }
```

Comment: Spinnaker is assigning those single quotes automatically.

Comment: Isn't there a way to tell spinnaker that the value is int (not string) so it doesn't add the quotes?

Comment: I could resolve it using the following notation in spinnaker.

'${ #toInt( parameters.Prodweightb ) }'
'${ #toInt( parameters.Blineweightb ) }'
'${ #toInt( parameters.Canaryweightb ) }'